# System GMM while Dependent Variable lies within [0, 1]

Tags: panel-data, econometrics, stata, generalized-moments

Is it possible to utilise the system GMM estimator using xtabond2 when our dependent variable lies within the interval [0, 1]. Moreover, the mass point is at around 0.

Thank you,

Sagnik

Answer (score 2):

GMM does not impose distrubutional assumptions on the errors, so you can *estimate* the model and the standard errors; *interpreting* the model for testing and inference might be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such restriction on dependent variable to apply GMM. You can apply GMM even if dependent variable is binary.

For more detail you can refer:

[System Equation by Instrumental Variable, Chapter 8, Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data by Wooldridge, 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262232588)